# Iterar arreglo de objetos para obtener todos los valores

Tags: javascript, array

Quiero iterar este arreglo de objetos, quiero obtener los valores:

```
level1 john does
leven2 juan perez
```

```js
var obj = [{
  "level1": {
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe"
  }
}, {
  "level2": {
    first: "juan",
    last: "perez"
  }
}]

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

Comment: Los elementos del array incluido en el código son objetos no JSON.

Comment: @Rubén esta bien entendido!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción más

```js
var obj = [{
  "level1": {
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe"
  }
}, {
  "level2": {
    first: "juan",
    last: "perez"
  }
}]

// Primero iteramos en el arreglo obj
obj.forEach(function(item) {
  // Luego iteramos las llaves de cada elemento del arreglo
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key){
    /* 
     * Registramos en la consola la llave y los valores de las propiedades first y
     * last de cada elemento del arreglo
     */
     console.log(key, item[key].first, item[key].last);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes auxiliarte de:

- `for of` que sirve para recorrer o iterar sobre objetos
- `Object.entries` devolverá un arreglo multidimensional de los valores del objeto; estableciendo una clave y un valor.

> Haciendo uso de `Object.entries` el areglo multidimensional de tu objeto quedaría así, para posteriormente por cada nivel de recorrido que se efectúe por los `for of` se puedan recuperar sus valores por medio de las claves:

```
[["0", [object Object] {
  level1: [object Object] {
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe"
  }
}], ["1", [object Object] {
  level2: [object Object] {
    first: "juan",
    last: "perez"
  }
}]]
```

- Como tu objeto, dentro de si a su vez tiene otros objetos anidados entonces se hace necesario iterar en 2 ocasiones para poder alcanzar dichos niveles y recuperar los valores de las claves: `first` y `last` de este modo:

```js
var obj = [{
  "level1": {
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe"
  }
}, {
  "level2": {
    first: "juan",
    last: "perez"
  }
}]

for (let [clave1, valor1] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    let claves = Object.keys(valor1)
    for (let [clave2, valor2] of Object.entries(valor1)) {
      console.log(`${claves} ${valor2["first"]} ${valor2["last"]}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por la observación @Rubén, no creo haberlo hecho del mejor modo pero logré obtener el resultado

Comment: No hay de que :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = [{
  "level1": {
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe"
  }
}, {
  "level2": {
    first: "juan",
    last: "perez"
  }
}]
for(objeto of obj){
  var clave=Object.keys(objeto)[0];
  console.log(clave+" "+objeto[clave]["first"]+" "+objeto[clave]["last"])
}
/*Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key, obj[key]);
});*/
```